# How do I re-run updates (change module schema version)?

Tags: 8

I'm working on a module, and I changed a couple field types in the schema. I didn't take a backup before testing it and messed up the DB (it's just a dev site). Anyway, I reinstalled everything, and the schema version is set to that of the highest update. However, I actually do need to run the update; a View I have wouldn't install if I had the updated schema in the module code, so I figured this would be a good way to test that update.

How do I reset the schema version of my module to a particular version? In Drupal 7, I would have done this:

`drush sqlq "UPDATE system SET schema_version=8102 WHERE name='flllpdf' AND type='module'"`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

While accessing state directly works, you can also just use the API: [drupal_set_installed_schema_version()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21schema.inc/function/drupal_set_installed_schema_version/8), which has existed since 4.7, as visible on the linked documentation page. This function is deprecated in Drupal 9.3.0 and removed in 10.0.0, where you should use [\Drupal\Core\Update\UpdateHookRegistry::setInstalledVersion()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Update%21UpdateHookRegistry.php/function/UpdateHookRegistry%3A%3AsetInstalledVersion/9.3.x) instead.

To set it from drush:

```
drush ev "drupal_set_installed_schema_version('fillpdf', 8012)"
```

<sup>Note: In Drupal 7 you need to add extra `include 'includes/install.inc';`.</sup>

or (Drupal >= 9.3):

```
drush ev "\Drupal::service('update.update_hook_registry')->setInstalledVersion('fillpdf', 8012);"
```

Comment: Also nice if you simply need to check quick:    drush ev "echo drupal_get_installed_schema_version('MODULE')"; https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21schema.inc/function/drupal_get_installed_schema_version/8.3.x

Comment: or drush pm-info modulename

Comment: @Beanluc - using `drush pm-info modulename` will give you the version of the module, but not the schema update version.

Comment: Where do you need to add this: 'Note: In Drupal 7 you need to add extra include 'includes/install.inc';.' in the command or in the .module?

Answer (score 25):

Drupal 8 now uses the `keyvalue` service to store information about the schema version. This is the same API the [State API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/state) itself uses.

Value information is serialized when stored in the database, so using a direct SQL query is sub-optimal. Instead, use `drush php-eval` (or a script that bootstraps Drupal, if you don't have Drush) to execute the following:

```
<?php
  \Drupal::keyValue('system.schema')->set('fillpdf', (int) 8102);
?>
```

Change `fillpdf` and `8102` to your module name and desired schema version, respectively.

The Drush form of this command is:

`drush ev "\Drupal::keyValue('system.schema')->set('fillpdf', (int) 8102)";`

Comment: Note that if you're using ddev then this throws a bash error. You'll need to `ddev ssh` into the vm and then the command runs fine.

Comment: It's possible to run it from bash, but the escaping is a bit of a pain, so `ddev ssh` is indeed easier.

Answer (score 0):

To SET and GET module updates via code (without Drush). Below is the code

```
GET  = drupal_get_installed_schema_version('moduleName');

SET = drupal_set_installed_schema_version("moduleName", "8000");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can also go update it directly in the database. If you're using something like Sequel Pro (mac) or whatever database UI tool windows/linux has it's really easy. Arguably not the best idea, and would not advise doing this against a production level database, but it'll get the job done!

Table = key_value

collection = system.schema 
name = fillpdf (your_module) 
value = update to i:8102;

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 10, the service `update.update_hook_registry` provides two wrapper functions to get and set the module installed version:

GET:

```
drush ev "echo \Drupal::service('update.update_hook_registry')->getInstalledVersion('mymodule')"
```

SET:

```
drush ev "\Drupal::service('update.update_hook_registry')->setInstalledVersion('mymodule', 8105)"
```